# update the parent component state doesn't reflect the change in child component

Tags: reactjs

I am iterating through a list and rendering a table in the parent component. One of the column calls a child component and I am passing the value in the list as argument. When the list is updated in the parent component, the table is getting refreshed, however, the child component is not getting the updated values.

```
 <div>
          {this.state.sessions.length <= 0 ? (
            <p id='noSessions'>
              <FormattedMessage id='Sessions.Unavailable.Message' />
            </p>
          ) : (
            <Table striped bordered hover id='sessionTable'>
              <thead>
                <tr id='sessionTableHeader'>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>
                    <FormattedMessage id='Course Name' />
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <FormattedMessage id='Session.Date.ColumnName' />
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <FormattedMessage id='Session.Start.Time' />
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <FormattedMessage id='Session.End.Time' />
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <FormattedMessage id='Session.Location' />
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    <FormattedMessage id='Instructor' />
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {this.state.sessions.map((session, uniquekey) => (
                  <tr key={uniquekey}>
                    <td>
                      <Checkbox
                        id={'sessionCheckbox' + session.sessionId}
                        checked={
                          this.state.checkedStatusOfSessions[session.sessionId] ?
                            this.state.checkedStatusOfSessions[session.sessionId] :
                            false
                        }
                        onChange={(event) => this.selectSession(session.sessionId, event)}
                      />
                    </td>
                    <td>{session.courseName}</td>
                    <td>
                      {new Date(session.sessionDate).toLocaleDateString(
                          getUserLocale(),
                          DATE_OPTIONS
                      )}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      {new Date(session.sessionStartTime).toLocaleTimeString(
                          getUserLocale(),
                          TIME_OPTIONS
                      )}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      {new Date(session.sessionEndTime).toLocaleTimeString(
                          getUserLocale(),
                          TIME_OPTIONS
                      )}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <SessionLocationManagementComponent
                        sessionId={session.sessionId}
                        sessionLocation={session.sessionLocation}
                      />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      {session.firstName} {session.lastName}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </Table>
          )}
        </div>
```

SessionLocationManagementComponent is the child component and the sessionId and location values are not getting updated when this.state.sessions is getting set. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include that `SessionLocationManagementComponent` component code in your question so we may see how it handles/processes incoming prop changes? Can you also share how `this.state.sessions` is possibly updated?

Comment: I am updating the sessions variable using setState when delete functionality is performed and the props obtained in the child component, I am setting them to state variable and using it.

Comment: I am not sure you pick up your key correctly. This `key={uniquekey}` suggests that you use the item's index. However, indexes can point to different elements in subsequent renders. Why not just `key={session.sessionId}`? This way you have stable keys between renders.

Comment: Thank you so much. changing the unique key worked.

Comment: Can this be posted as an answer?